# Combining a loop and an if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets. 
Sheet 1 contains the data I want to copy.
If you can provide me with a hint on how to approach, I should be able to code the rest on my own.

My logic was to create a loop, that would select all cells if a condition is met. This condition would be,
if cell(i,1) = cell(i+1,1)

I have attached 2 photos, the first is on how the original data in sheet 1 looks, and the second is sheet 2 with how the data looks after transformation.
[image: image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Here is my code where I get an error (Next without For)

```
Sub Loop_if()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ws("sheet2")

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
For i = 2 To 23000

    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
    Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 25)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws.Select
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True


End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Try to code with your logic, which sounds correct.  Then when you get stuck or hit an error that you cannot overcome, come back with the code and ask a specific question about the block/error.  Stack Overflow is not a sounding board, but a place to help with specific problems in existing code.

Comment: thanks for the feedback scott. I will post my code! Cheers!

Comment: I think you should verbalise the kind of transformation you want to achieve. And you might want to try and operate on ranges and transform ranges (I am not a VBA person).

Comment: @ScottCraner hey scott give my code a look. Hopefully it sets the base well and you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: you're missing an 'end if' statement.  see how you have two 'if'' statements....you only have 1 'end if'. start there...

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you don't close IF statement with "End IF"
You have 2 IF's and you need 2 "End IF"

```
   Sub Loop_if()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ws("sheet2")

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    For i = 2 To 23000

        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 25)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ws.Select
        End If
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True


    End If
    Next i
```

or something like that:

```
Sub Loop_if()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ws("sheet2")

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
For i = 2 To 23000

    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
    Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 25)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws.Select
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True


End If
Next i
```